# How to rewrite this request using async/await syntax?

Tags: javascript, async-await

Here's the task:

1. You need to make a GET request for the resource: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts using fetch method
2. Save the response to response.json file
3. Save only those items, where id < 20

What I wrote:

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'response.json');

fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        const refined = data.filter(item => item.id < 20);
        const stringified = JSON.stringify(refined);

        fs.appendFile(filePath, stringified, err => {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
        });
    });
```

How to write the same fetch, but with async/await syntax?

Comment: `const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')`

Comment: `const data = await res.json()`

Comment: your snippet has an error "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined"

Answer (score 3):

`await` keyword can only be used inside an `async` function, so you need to write an async function that makes the API request to fetch the data

```
async function fetchData() {
   const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
   const data = await response.json();

   const refined = data.filter(item => item.id < 20);
   const stringified = JSON.stringify(refined);
   
   // promise version of appendFile function from fs.promises API
   await fs.appendFile(filePath, stringified);
}
```

`fs` module of nodeJS has functions that use promises instead of callbacks. if you don't want to use callback version, you will need to use promise version of `appendFile` function.

You can import the promise version of `fs` module as `require('fs').promises` or `require('fs/promises')`.

To handle errors, make sure that code that calls this function has a `catch` block to catch and handle any errors that might be thrown from this function. You could also wrap the code in this function with `try-catch` block to handle the errors inside this function.

---

**Side tip:** If you want to write data in the file in easily readable format, change

```
const stringified = JSON.stringify(refined);
```

to

```
const stringified = JSON.stringify(refined, null, 4);
```

Comment: If you down vote, please add a comment on why you did so, this is a valid answer and does not deserve to be down voted.

Answer (score 1):

Below snippet could help you (tested in node v14)

```js
const fetch = require("node-fetch")

const fs = require("fs")
const path = require("path")
const filePath = path.join(__dirname, "response.json")

async function execute() {
  const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
  const data = await res.json()

  const refined = data.filter((item) => item.id < 20)
  const stringified = JSON.stringify(refined)

  fs.appendFile(filePath, stringified, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err
    }
  })
}

execute()
```